# Atom keybindings and the LaTeX package

Tags: latex, atom-editor

I want to change the keybinding for building in LaTeX from the default ctrl-alt-b to cmd-b. Settings suggests I copy paste

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar~='latex']':
  'cmd-b': 'latex:build'
```

into the keymap.cson file but upon saving it I get the error message

```
[stdin]:20:34: error: unexpected latex
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar~='latex']':
                                 ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the whole expression is inside a pair of single quotes, you need to use different quotes around `latex`:

```
"atom-text-editor[data-grammar~='latex']":
```

or

```
'atom-text-editor[data-grammar~="latex"]':
```

Also note, that you will likely run into a conflict with existing keybindings. The [`keybinding-resolver`](https://github.com/atom/keybinding-resolver) package is a great helper to find conflicting keybindings.